# UITableView blurry Header on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7

On the new iOS 7 most of the redesigned App´s does have a little blurry Header, especially Facebook or Instagram...

Does somebody know how to do that?!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a public API for it, however you can use the layer (or the view itself) of a UIToolbar to blur contents behind a view. There is an example project [here](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur).

Comment: Is that also possible to do with an UIImage?! To blur contents behind an UIImage?!

Comment: Are you trying to blur a UIImage (there is sample code on the WWDC '13 site - look for UIImage effects) or are you trying to blur a UIImageView? With the latter you can just stick the UIToolbar in front @chrizstone

Comment: I have an UiImage at the top of my UITableView...Now i want to blur everything behind that UIImage just like Facebook or Instagram do...